# List of file paths to iteratively pass through sourced python function in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reticulate

I have come up with a python function that I have confirmed works just fine. I am trying to put this into a Shiny app using Shiny's `reticulate`. I am not super familiar with Shiny but need to use it anyhow.

To give a bit of background on what I am doing, I've written some python code that takes takes multiple files and matches strings based on one common list of strings. This code works fine when I run the python files on my machine.

I need to make this available to others using a shiny app, where they can upload their files, then have the app run the underlying python code.

So far, I have set up the shiny app so that it can take in multiple files. I am having a hard time thinking about how I can use `reactive` to make a list of the file path names to then send to my python code (which includes a step to open and read the file) so it can do its thing.

This is the code that I have for my app thus far:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

# define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel('Counter of Gendered Language'),
    fileInput("upload", "Choose a folder",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept = c('text')),
    tableOutput('text'),
    downloadButton('output', 'Download Count File .csv'))
# define server behavior
server <- function(input, output){
    # Setup
        #* Load libraries
    library(reticulate)
        #* Use virtual environment for python dependencies
use_virtualenv('file/path/py_venv', required = TRUE)
        #* Source code
    source_python('code/counting_gendered_words.py')
        #* Load list of words to match raw text against
    dictionary <- read.csv('data/word_rating.csv')
    text <- reactive(
        list <- list.files(path = input$upload[['name']])
        )
    output$counted <- gendered_word_counter(dictionary, text())
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
     filename = function(){
         paste0(input$upload, ".csv")
     },
     content = function(file){
         vroom::vroom_write(text$counted, file)
     }
 )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What it tells me when I run this app is that:

> Error : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
>
> - You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.

So what I am wanting to do is basically just pass each file name that someone uploads to the app and pass that file's name into my `gendered_word_counter()` python function.

How would I go about this?

I'm super confident that I just am being a newbie and it is probably a super simple fix. Any help from those who are more comfortable with Shiny would be much appreciated!

Edit: I notice that my code is only calling the names of the files which is meaningless for me without the contents of the uploaded files! Would it be better if I read the files in the shiny app instead of in my .py file?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the app without the python code, but i can see that this line:

`output$counted <- gendered_word_counter(dictionary, text())`

has a reactive object (`text()`) being called with no reactive context. It should be wrapped in `observe` or `observeEvent`.

```
observe({
  output$counted <- gendered_word_counter(dictionary, text())
})
```

Also let's add the parenthesis here:

```
    content = function(file){
      vroom::vroom_write(text()$counted, file)
    }
```